# In Google Sheet, how do you use SUMIFS with OR logic matching a list of items?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

In order to clarify the scenario, please check the example here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E_xyPvkTIObG5JA4UfG1EQa74cFEc9QiznidJ4HSmEY/edit?usp=sharing

What I want to do here is to:

1. filter by date (matching a certain date)
2. filter by product id (matching a list of specified ids)
3. sum up the total

I did try to find some ideas, though none of them worked, including the solution in the article below
https://exceljet.net/formula/sumifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logic

Really appriciate if someone could point me in the right direction, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=QUERY({'raw data'!A2:C}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col3) 
  where Col2 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 'ids to match'!A2:A)&"' 
  group by Col1 
  order by Col1 desc
  label sum(Col3)''")
```

[image]

Comment: oh nice idea, TEXTJOIN never crossed my mind, thanks!

Comment: sorry another question, i tried your method and twisted a little bit, using date as a secondary condition where dates are pre-populated 

=QUERY({'raw data'!A2:C}, 
 "select sum(Col3) 
  where (Col2 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 'ids to match'!A2:A)&"') and (Col1 = "&A2&")
  label sum(Col3)''")

but that broke the formula, should i be using INDIRECT or something instead?

Thanks again

Comment: @DanielL. in query whenever you do aggregation (sum,min,max,count,avg) you always need to have `group by`

Answer (score 0):

Sumifs is different than Sumif. You also have some text mixed with numbers. Your dates are text while Column b is numeric. Try this:

```
=Sumifs(C:C:,A:A,"2022-09-08",B:B,82267,B:B,82602) + 
 Sumifs(C:C:,A:A,"2022-09-08",B:B,82267,B:B,82602B:B,82604)
```

As Player() points out, if you have too many products to include, using sumifs would get pretty tedious and you ought to consider using a different function (i'd use filter). However since your question was Sumifs related, that's your answer.

To illustrate how this would work with something Filter, you could do this:

```
=sum(filter('raw data'!C:C,('raw data'!A:A=A2)*
  (isnumber(match('raw data'!B:B,'ids to match'!A:A,0)))))
```

Comment: I don't think the first formula would work because you'd get 'AND' logic between the three numbers which would always work out to be False. The other one, great.

Comment: You would need =Sumifs(C:C,A:A,"2022-09-08",B:B,82267)+
Sumifs(C:C,A:A,"2022-09-08",B:B,82602)+
Sumifs(C:C,A:A,"2022-09-08",B:B,82604) - not worth submitting as an answer I think!

Comment: Oh you're right. Thanks! I get dizzy whenever I compete against Player()'s answers....